# Is it possible to develop a hybrid (native + html5) app for Blackberry?

Tags: html, blackberry, webview, native, embeddable

On Android, since the browser is embeddable inside a native screen, we can build hybrid apps with some screens as native and some with an embedded Webview. Is it possible to embed the browser inside a native Blackberry screen and have cross-talk between native and JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to embed a browser inside a blackberry screen. Yes you can have cross-talk between native and JavaScript code. Please refer to browserfield2demo app in samples. It shows how to do what you want to do.

Check out `net.rim.device.api.script` at http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/script/package-summary.html